# Exclude starting words from SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, words

I'm trying to make a list of movies. First I've got a query that gets all the first letters from the movies:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(film_title, 1) FROM ms_films ORDER BY film_title
```

Second I've got a query that selects all movies that start with the specific letter:

```
SELECT * FROM ms_films WHERE film_title LIKE 'H%'
```

Ofcourse quite some movies start with 'The' or the dutch word for it 'De'. Is there any way I can exclude those starting words from these 2 queries?

Basically a movie like 'The next three days' should be categorised under the N in both queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE` to remove them

```
SELECT * FROM ms_films WHERE REPLACE(film_title, "The", "") LIKE 'H%'
```

Obviously this removes all the occurrences of The, but it should not matter in your case.

If you need more sophisticated search patterns you can also use `REGEXP` (or its alias `RLIKE`) instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: A drawback: no index will be used for this query.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a common task in your application, I would suggest introducing a CHAR(1) column, where the first (actual) letter of the title will be stored. You can create an Index on this column which will be pretty fast, since it's one byte only.